# Modal Dialog in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am new to web development.  I am currently using a .js modal dialog box that I found on the [internet](http://javascript.about.com/library/blmodald1.htm) that is ok for now.  What I want to know is, is there a nicer way to do this.  Should I look at using jquery?

Thanks

Comment: When asking this I didn't have a complete understanding of what I was after. I have ended up using the jQuery UI dialog [link](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the popular [Prototype JS library](http://api.prototypejs.org/). Here's how you would do it in Prototype. The idea will be very similar in nearly all other JS libraries.

**HTML:**

```
<div style="display: none" id="message"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#message {
 position: absolute;
 left: 40%;
 top: 40%;
}
```

**JS:**

```
function modal(text) {
 $('message').update(text);
 $('message').appear();
}

modal('Any text you want to appear in the modal box');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use jquery fancybox. It's great and works as well"